# Tosca Error Execution " multiple Firefox windows are not support at the moment"

Tags: error-handling, tosca

Can someone answer my question about tosca commander? Got an error message while running scratchbook.

Comment: someone definitely can anwer your question. But what is your question then?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem yesterday. I found out I had enabled the same "Tosca Automation Extension for Microsoft Edge" twice, probably the administrator of my remote desktop added the second extension.

Hope it could help you.
Christy